# Make third-party cookie settings per site persistent on Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

### Background

When you use extensions on GitHub Codespaces, you have to add the site `[*.]github.dev` to `Sites that can always use cookies` settings and enable third-party cookies on this site if you block third-party cookies on Google Chrome like this:

[image]

### Problem

After adding the site to the cookie setting, sometimes the `Sites that can always use cookies` settings go back to empty.
The problem doesn't reproduce just after the adding site. But when I restart Chrome a few days later, these settings go to empty.

### Question

How can I make the `Sites that can always use cookies` setting persistent on Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of this problem.

When I clear browsing data from Chrome, I have checked the `Site settings` option. This option clears the `Sites that can always use cookies` setting.

[image: Screenshot of "Clear browsing data" dialog]

I couldn't find a way to preserve the `Sites that can always use cookies` setting and clear other data from Chrome.